# Setup my sqlite database on userdata path on electron

Tags: database, sqlite, electron

I managed to copy my database (included in my application) directly into the userdata folder.

but I would like to setup my database directly from this folder in my file dedicated to the sql query.

but with the contextisolation impossible to do it. I tried with the contextBridge and I manage to retrieve the folder path from my index.html but not from my js file.

Can anyone help me?

Main.js

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const { dirname } = require("path");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const { electron } = require("process");
const { URLSearchParams } = require("url");
const ipc = ipcMain;
process.env['ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS'] = 'true';

// Window
function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1600,
    height: 900,
    minWidth: 1024,
    minHeight: 640,
    closable: true,
    darkTheme: true,
    frame: false,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, "./images/ico.ico"),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      //devTools: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });
  
  win.loadFile("index.html");
  //win.webContents.openDevTools();

  ipc.on("app/close", () => {
    app.quit()
  })
  
  ipc.on("app/minimize", () => {
    win.minimize()
  })

  ipc.on("app/reload", () => {
    win.reload()
  })
  
  ipc.on("app/size", () => {
    if (win.isMaximized()) {
      win.restore();
      win.resizable = true
    } else {
      win.maximize();
      win.resizable = false
    }
  })
}

// When Electron Ready
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

preload.js

```js
const {ipcRenderer, contextBridge} = require("electron");

const db = require("./js/db");

const getNbonus = () => {
    return db.getNbonus();
}

const getTotalCost = () => {
    return db.getTotalCost();
}

const getTotalWin = () => {
    return db.getTotalWin();
}

const getProfitLoss = () => {
    return db.getProfitLoss();
}

const newHunt = (title,start,date) => {
    db.newHunt(title,start,date);
}

const date = () => {
    return db.date();
}

const ProfitLoss = () => {
    return db.ProfitLoss();
}

const bonushunt = () => {
    return db.bonushunt();
}

const deletehunt = (id) => {
    db.deletehunt(id);
}

const updatehunt = (title,start,date,id) => {
    db.updatehunt(title,start,date,id);
}

const ProfitLossbyid = (id) => {
    db.ProfitLossbyid(id);
    return db.ProfitLossbyid(id);
}

const CountBonusbyid = (id) => {
    db.CountBonusbyid(id);
    return db.CountBonusbyid(id);
}

const startbyid = (id) => {
    db.startbyid(id);
    return db.startbyid(id);
}

const hunt = (id) => {
    db.hunt(id);
    return db.hunt(id);
}

const slots = () => {
    return db.slots();
}

const newbonus = (idhunt,slotid,betsize) => {
    db.newbonus(idhunt,slotid,betsize);
}

const deletebonus = (id) => {
    db.deletebonus(id);
}

const getidhunt = (title) => {
    db.getidhunt(title);
    return db.getidhunt(title);
}

const updatebonus = (idhunt,id,bet,payout) => {
    db.updatebonus(idhunt,id,bet,payout);
}

const bonushuntpage = () => {
    return db.bonushuntpage();
}

const avghuntwin = () => {
    return db.avghuntwin();
}

const bestslot = (id) => {
    db.bestslot(id);
    return db.bestslot(id);
}

const worstslot = (id) => {
    db.worstslot(id);
    return db.worstslot(id);
}

const amountwon = (id) => {
    db.amountwon(id);
    return db.amountwon(id);
}

const avgrequire = (id) => {
    db.avgrequire(id);
    return db.avgrequire(id);
}

const avg = (id) => {
    db.avg(id);
    return db.avg(id);
}

const bex = (id) => {
    db.bex(id);
    return db.bex(id);
}

const avgx = (id) => {
    db.avgx(id);
    return db.avgx(id);
}

const remain = (id) => {
    db.remain(id);
    return db.remain(id);
}

const cent = (id) => {
    db.cent(id);
    return db.cent(id);
}

const allslot = () => {
    return db.allslot();
}

const updateslot = (id,slot,provider,rtp,volatility,potential) => {
    db.updateslot(id,slot,provider,rtp,volatility,potential);
}

const provider = () => {
    return db.provider();
}

const providerbyid = (id) => {
    db.providerbyid(id)
    return db.providerbyid(id);
}

const newslot = (slot,provider,rtp,volatility,potential) => {
    db.newslot(slot,provider,rtp,volatility,potential);
}

const API = {
    window: {
        close: () => ipcRenderer.send("app/close"),
        minimize: () => ipcRenderer.send("app/minimize"),
        size: () => ipcRenderer.send("app/size"),
        reload: () => ipcRenderer.send("app/reload")
    }
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("app", API)
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
    getNbonus: getNbonus,
    getTotalCost: getTotalCost,
    getTotalWin: getTotalWin,
    getProfitLoss: getProfitLoss,
    newHunt: newHunt,
    date: date,
    bonushunt: bonushunt,
    deletehunt: deletehunt,
    ProfitLoss: ProfitLoss,
    updatehunt: updatehunt,
    ProfitLossbyid: ProfitLossbyid,
    CountBonusbyid: CountBonusbyid,
    startbyid: startbyid,
    hunt: hunt,
    slots: slots,
    newbonus: newbonus,
    deletebonus: deletebonus,
    getidhunt: getidhunt,
    updatebonus: updatebonus,
    bonushuntpage: bonushuntpage,
    avghuntwin: avghuntwin,
    bestslot: bestslot,
    worstslot: worstslot,
    amountwon: amountwon,
    avgrequire: avgrequire,
    avg: avg,
    bex: bex,
    avgx: avgx,
    remain: remain,
    cent: cent,
    allslot: allslot,
    updateslot: updateslot,
    provider: provider,
    providerbyid: providerbyid,
    newslot: newslot
})
```

db.js

```js
const database = require('better-sqlite3-multiple-ciphers')
const db = new database('bh.db')

exports.getNbonus = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT count(*) as nbonus FROM bonus_hunt');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}

exports.getTotalCost = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT SUM(start) as totalcost FROM bonus_hunt');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}

exports.getTotalWin = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT SUM(payout) as totalwin FROM hunt');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}

exports.getProfitLoss = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT ((SELECT SUM(payout) as totalwin FROM hunt)-(SELECT SUM(start) as totalcost FROM bonus_hunt)) as ProfitLoss');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}

exports.newHunt = (title,start,date) => {
    const sql = db.prepare('INSERT INTO bonus_hunt (title,start,date) VALUES (:title, :start, :date)');
    sql.run({title,start,date})
}

exports.date = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT date FROM bonus_hunt');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}

exports.ProfitLoss = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT ((SELECT SUM(payout) FROM hunt where hunt.id_bonushunt = bonus_hunt.id)-(SELECT start FROM bonus_hunt where bonus_hunt.id = hunt.id_bonushunt)) as profitloss from bonus_hunt JOIN hunt on bonus_hunt.id = hunt.id_bonushunt GROUP BY id');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}

exports.bonushunt = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT id, title, start,date,(Select count(*) from hunt where hunt.id_bonushunt = bonus_hunt.id) as nbbonus, ((SELECT SUM(payout) FROM hunt where hunt.id_bonushunt = bonus_hunt.id)-(SELECT start FROM bonus_hunt where bonus_hunt.id = hunt.id_bonushunt)) as profitloss from bonus_hunt JOIN hunt on bonus_hunt.id = hunt.id_bonushunt GROUP BY id');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}

exports.deletehunt = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('DELETE from bonus_hunt WHERE id=:id');
    stmt.run ({id})
}

exports.updatehunt = (title,start,date,id) => {
    const sql = db.prepare('UPDATE bonus_hunt SET title=:title, start=:start, date=:date WHERE id=:id');
    sql.run({title,start,date,id})
}

exports.ProfitLossbyid = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT id, ((SELECT SUM(payout) FROM hunt where hunt.id_bonushunt = bonus_hunt.id)-(SELECT start FROM bonus_hunt where bonus_hunt.id = hunt.id_bonushunt)) as profitloss from bonus_hunt JOIN hunt on bonus_hunt.id = hunt.id_bonushunt WHERE id=:id GROUP BY id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.CountBonusbyid = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT count(*) as NB_Bonus FROM hunt where id_bonushunt=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.startbyid = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT start FROM bonus_hunt where id=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.hunt = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT hunt.id_bonushunt as idhunt, hunt.id_slots as id, slots.slot, slots.provider, hunt.bet_size, hunt.payout, hunt.multiplier from hunt join slots on hunt.id_slots = slots.id where id_bonushunt=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.slots = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('select id, slot FROM slots');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res
}

exports.newbonus = (idhunt,slotid,betsize) => {
    const sql = db.prepare('INSERT INTO hunt (id_bonushunt,id_slots,bet_size) VALUES (:idhunt, :slotid, :betsize)');
    sql.run({idhunt,slotid,betsize})
}

exports.deletebonus = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('DELETE from hunt WHERE id_slots=:id');
    stmt.run ({id})
}

exports.getidhunt = (title) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT id from bonus_hunt where title=:title');
    const res = stmt.all({title});
    return res
}

exports.updatebonus = (idhunt,id,bet,payout) => {
    const sql = db.prepare('UPDATE hunt SET bet_size=:bet, payout=:payout WHERE id_bonushunt=:idhunt and id_slots=:id');
    sql.run({idhunt,id,bet,payout})
}

exports.bonushuntpage = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT id, title, start,date,(Select count(*) from hunt where hunt.id_bonushunt = bonus_hunt.id) as nbbonus from bonus_hunt group by id');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}

exports.avghuntwin = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT ((Select sum(payout))/(Select count(*))/(Select count(*) from bonus_hunt)) as avg from hunt');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}

exports.bestslot = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('select slot,max(payout) as best from (select payout, slots.slot, bonus_hunt.id from hunt join slots on hunt.id_slots = slots.id join bonus_hunt on hunt.id_bonushunt = bonus_hunt.id) where id=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
    
}

exports.worstslot = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('select slot,min(payout) as worst from (select payout, slots.slot, bonus_hunt.id from hunt join slots on hunt.id_slots = slots.id join bonus_hunt on hunt.id_bonushunt = bonus_hunt.id) where id=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.amountwon = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('select sum(payout) as amountwon from hunt where id_bonushunt=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.avgrequire = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT ((bonus_hunt.start - SUM(hunt.payout)) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hunt WHERE hunt.payout IS NULL)) as BE FROM hunt JOIN bonus_hunt on bonus_hunt.id = hunt.id_bonushunt where id_bonushunt=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.avg = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT avg(hunt.payout) as AVG FROM hunt where id_bonushunt=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.bex = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT ((SELECT ((bonus_hunt.start - SUM(hunt.payout)) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hunt WHERE hunt.payout IS NULL)) FROM hunt JOIN bonus_hunt on bonus_hunt.id = hunt.id_bonushunt where id_bonushunt=:id) / avg(hunt.bet_size)) as BEX FROM hunt WHERE hunt.payout IS NULL');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.avgx = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT avg(hunt.multiplier) as AVGX FROM hunt where id_bonushunt=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.remain = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) as Remain FROM hunt WHERE hunt.payout IS NULL and id_bonushunt=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.cent = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) as cent FROM hunt WHERE hunt.multiplier >= 100 and id_bonushunt=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.allslot = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT id,slot,provider,rtp,volatility,potential from slots');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}

exports.updateslot = (id,slot,provider,rtp,volatility,potential) => {
    const sql = db.prepare('UPDATE slots SET slot=:slot, provider=:provider, rtp=:rtp, volatility=:volatility, potential=:potential WHERE id=:id');
    sql.run({id,slot,provider,rtp,volatility,potential})
}

exports.provider = () => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT id, provider from slots group by provider');
    const res = stmt.all();
    return res;
}

exports.providerbyid = (id) => {
    const stmt = db.prepare('SELECT provider FROM slots where id=:id');
    const res = stmt.all({id});
    return res
}

exports.newslot = (slot,provider,rtp,volatility,potential) => {
    const sql = db.prepare('INSERT INTO slots (slot,provider,rtp,volatility,potential) VALUES (:slot, :provider, :rtp, :volatility, :potential)');
    sql.run({slot,provider,rtp,volatility,potential})
}
```

i want to get userdata path for my database

Comment: So, just to confirm, you have manually saved your sqlite database in the `userdata` folder and you wish to access your database from the `userdata` folder? If so, the Electron [`app.getPath(name)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname) function is what you will be looking for. If you need help in implementing it let me know.

Comment: @midnight-coding yes i want help to do this with contextbridge, I succeeded but I have an error in the db.js file when I do a log, yet it works perfectly when I do it in an html file I don't understand

Comment: @midnight-coding
So i try to send just path from main to preload to my db.js without success
I try  to define my new db in main and send to preload to my db.js without succes too

Comment: Ok, I just familiarised myself with `better-sqlite3-multiple-ciphers`, a specialised fork of `sqlite3`. The database path can be set when creating / opening the database which is great. Am I correct in stating that currently you are running your db in your render thread (and using your `preload.js` to transfer data between process when needed)? If so, I would like to recommend a clearly separated way of doing things where all your db functionality is in your main process, and via the use of your `preload.js` script, only data is transferred between your main and render thread(s). Sound good?

Comment: @midnight-coding so I need to restart, and just use main + preload  without use my file db.js right ?

Comment: Correct, just use your `better-sqlite3-multiple-ciphers` functions within your main thread (in different Javascript files if needed for separation), and use IPC to forward on your (JSON) db results to your render thread for DOM insertion. Let me know if you need any help.